# Recuperar campo com join na view em RUBY/RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estou com uma grande duvida, sou iniciante em Ruby, e não estou conseguindo imprimir o valor de um campo na minha view, o resultado é esse.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu Model:

```
    class Pedido < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :produtos      

      scope :waiting, -> { where(status: 1) }
end
```

Meu Controller:

```
class Backoffice::PedidosController < BackofficeController

  def index
    @pedidos = Pedido.waiting       
  end

end
```

E na minha View esta assim:

```
<tbody>               
  <% @pedidos.each do |pedido| %>
    <tr> 
      <th><%=pedido.id%></th>
      <th><%=pedido.status%></th>
      <th><%=pedido.created_at%></th>
      <th><%=pedido.produtos.select(:valor) %></th>
     </tr>
   <% end %>
 </tbody>
```

Ja tentei de varias formas e sempre imprime o que está no print, se eu mudo a linha para

> <%=pedido.produtos.produto %>

da erro na pagina.

Alguem pode me dar uma luz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente especificar qual o `Produto` da associação, por exemplo:

`<%= pedido.produtos.first.valor %>`
Neste caso, retorna o primeiro `Produto` da associação.

Não sei como será sua implementação, mas enfim, como `Pedido` tem muitos `Produtos`, quando você busca essa associação, retorna uma coleção de `Produtos`, e você precisa especificar qual você quer.

Ou caso, queira fazer uma soma do valor dos `Produtos`:

`<%= pedido.produtos.sum(:valor) %>`

Comment: Muito obrigado, tinha pensado exatamente isso, só não sabia como fazer. Agora tenho que pensar em uma maneira de apresentar todos os Produtos vinculados ao Pedido, mas para isso terei que alterar minha view. Tem alguma ideia de como precisarei implementar isso? Terei que percorrer um array? Muito obrigado.

Comment: Achei o comando <%= pedido.produtos.pluck (:valor) %> que apresenta os valores na minha view em forma de array, isso ja me da uma luz, tenho que pensar em uma logica para posteriormente apresentar esses dados em outra tela de melhor leitura para o usuario....Valeu

Comment: Sim, desta forma que está fazendo, terá que percorrer os produtos para mostrar todos os produtos (pedido.produtos.each). Caso não tenha feito ainda, eu faria um novo Controller (Produtos), para mostrar os Produtos do Pedido em outra página, assim ficaria mais organizada suas views. Dê uma olhada em nested routes, isso poderá te ajudar a ter uma ideia melhor do Rails para estes casos (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources)

Comment: Farei isso, muito obrigado Luis!